# Capturing browser-window height once on load with Jquery

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

When a user loads the webpage, I'd like to capture the height of their browser window and make a DIV that height; if they resize the window then the height of that DIV will not change. 
Here's an example: http://demo.rocknrolladesigns.com/html/jarvis/

I'm going for the effect of having a full-page background image with text over it and hiding all nav and content directly below the 'fold'.

Thx;)

Comment: I'm not really sure this comes under the general definition of "responsive design".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as simple as:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#background').css('height', $(window).height() + 'px');
  });
```

where `#background` is the ID of the DIV you're using as the background to the page. You should also set a separate style on the background; something similar to:

```
  #background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: ...
  }
```

should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to *create* the div? Replace `#foo` to whatever you want to append it to.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#foo').append('<div style="height: ' + $(window).height() + 'px;"></div>');
});
```

Comment: You need to add 'px' to the string as well; I'd edit your answer but unfortunately SO needs me to alter six characters.

Comment: @AdrianWragg Sorry, yes I completely forgot. I just edited it. I guess it would have worked anyways as the fallback for height value in CSS are pixels right?

Comment: Yup, it would have worked fine; adding px to it just gives a 'slightly more right' solution. :)